# Use libcryptsetup to open a plain encrypted partition

Tags: encryption

I have a deployed kiosk system which mounts an encrypted partition at boot time using crytpsetup and a key file on disk as such:

```
cryptsetup open --type plain --key-file /root/key.bin /dev/sda3 sda3
```

This yields a /dev/mapper/sda3 device which I can then mount for data access.

I am moving the key to a smart card and want to open the partition using libcryptsetup so the key is not exposed on the command line.  Unfortunately, the only example given in the cryptsetup source is for LUKS.

I have tried to reverse engineer the cryptsetup source to get the correct library calls but have been frustrated by the complexity of the options.

Are there examples of other projects which use the library for plain encryption or perhaps a skeleton of the library calls required to duplicate the actions of the command line invocation?

Answer (score -1):

The basic sequence of the library calls required for duplicating the actions on command line to open an encrypted partition using cryptsetup library will be as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <libcryptsetup.h>

int activate_and_check_status(const char *path, const char *device_name)
{
        struct crypt_device *cd;
        struct crypt_active_device cad;
        int r;
        /*
         * LUKS device activation example.
         * It's sequence of sub-steps: device initialization, LUKS header load
         * and the device activation itself.
         */
        r = crypt_init(&cd, path);
        if (r < 0 ) {
                printf("crypt_init() failed for %s.\n", path);
                return r;
        }
        /*
         * crypt_load() is used to load the LUKS header from block device
         * into crypt_device context.
         */
        r = crypt_load(cd,              /* crypt context */
                       CRYPT_LUKS1,     /* requested type */
                       NULL);           /* additional parameters (not used) */
        if (r < 0) {
                printf("crypt_load() failed on device %s.\n", crypt_get_device_name(cd));
                crypt_free(cd);
                return r;
        }
        /*
         * Device activation creates device-mapper devie mapping with name device_name.
         */
        r = crypt_activate_by_passphrase(cd,            /* crypt context */
                                         device_name,   /* device name to activate */
                                         CRYPT_ANY_SLOT,/* which slot use (ANY - try all) */
                                         "foo", 3,      /* passphrase */
                                         CRYPT_ACTIVATE_READONLY); /* flags */
        if (r < 0) {
                printf("Device %s activation failed.\n", device_name);
                crypt_free(cd);
                return r;
        }
        printf("LUKS device %s/%s is active.\n", crypt_get_dir(), device_name);
        printf("\tcipher used: %s\n", crypt_get_cipher(cd));
        printf("\tcipher mode: %s\n", crypt_get_cipher_mode(cd));
        printf("\tdevice UUID: %s\n", crypt_get_uuid(cd));
        /*
         * Get info about active device (query DM backend)
         */
        r = crypt_get_active_device(cd, device_name, &cad);
        if (r < 0) {
                printf("Get info about active device %s failed.\n", device_name);
                crypt_deactivate(cd, device_name);
                crypt_free(cd);
                return r;
        }
        printf("Active device parameters for %s:\n"
                "\tDevice offset (in sectors): %" PRIu64 "\n"
                "\tIV offset (in sectors)    : %" PRIu64 "\n"
                "\tdevice size (in sectors)  : %" PRIu64 "\n"
                "\tread-only flag            : %s\n",
                device_name, cad.offset, cad.iv_offset, cad.size,
                cad.flags & CRYPT_ACTIVATE_READONLY ? "1" : "0");
        crypt_free(cd);
        return 0;
}
```

The API references for luks format, open, activate and deactivate with examples for cryptsetup is available at this link:
[cryptsetup API](https://mbroz.fedorapeople.org/libcryptsetup_API/index.html#cactivate)

Comment: I am aware of the LUKS example and it is of no use since the partition is encrypted plain without LUKS headers.